# Android getting service UUIDs for a connected devices

Tags: android, bluetooth, uuid, serial-communication

So here's the complete story. I'm trying to develop an application that connects to my bike's bluetooth device and then starts a RFCOMM socket to a UUID. The issue is that the socket/service UUID is unknown to me and when I connect the bluetooth device (Bike) and get UUIDs using btDevice.getUuids(), I get 5 UUIDs and from that I can connect my socket to the UUIDs at position 0 and 1.
Now here's the catch. I downloaded a source code that works on a different version of bike for the same manufacture but not the model I have. The bluetooth connects, the socket connects but after the data transfer (Navigation data), nothing is being displayed on the bike screen. I believe I need to connect to a UUID that is specifically for navigation and I dont know how to discover that UUID.

My bike : KTM Duke 390

Sample app works on : KTM Duke 790

The UUID I'm talking about is used to transmit navigation updated to the bike's screen.

Comment: Do you have an app that uses the features you want to use, too? If yes enable Bluetooth HCI snoop log in Android developer settings and learn from the communication the app does with your bike.